# Can I somehow convert a tax credit for solar into cash?

Tags: united-states, taxes, new-york, tax-credit

A solar company in nyc told me that if I do with them solar I can get %20 on property tax 30% in federal tax and $5000 in tax
The 30% tax is non refundable and also $5000 .
Is there a way to use to my own benefit and to to convert it to cash in some how ?

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about tax credits for solar? What exactly do you mean by "use to my own benefit and to convert it to cash"? These are tax credits, they *are* for your benefit, and *save* you cash in reducing your tax bill.

Comment: If it's a nonrefundable credit, it's only a benefit if you owe that much tax in the first place. If your pre-credit tax bill is only $3000, a $5000 credit does not result in a $2000 refund; you "lose" the extra $2000 that could have been applied to a higher tax bill.

Comment: Though you may be able to carry over unused credits for some number of years. Check the details of that particular credit.

Answer (score 4):

There are both federal and (in some states) state tax credits that can be claimed to help offset the cost of installing a photovoltaic system. You do have to file an explicit form in order to claim these credits, and they are applied against any taxes you owe.

As @littleadv said, it's real money, even if it's just money that stays in your pocket rather than money passing through your pocket.

For the federal program, see https://www.energy.gov/eere/solar/homeowners-guide-federal-tax-credit-solar-photovoltaics

For New York State's program (since the question was about New York), see https://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/credits/solar_energy_system_equipment_credit.htm

Note that these are one-time credits that help you with the cost of purchasing and installing the photovoltaic system. It isn't 30% (or whatever) off your entire tax bill, and it's a one-time credit. Think of it as a rebate on your purchase price.

However there are other ways a photovoltaic system can return money to your pocket on an ongoing basis. In some areas, the electric company offers "net metering", where whenever you produce more electricity than you are consuming at that moment your meter runs backward -- selling that excess electricity back to the network at the same price they charge you. I've never had a month where the electric company owed me money on my monthly bill, but I've occasionally come close enough that all I was paying was their account maintenance fee.

Also, at least for now, running a photovoltaic system produces carbon credits (SRECs), which can be sold for some additional income. I don't actually like the carbon credit system very much, since it gives companies a way to avoid investing in improving their own energy efficiency, but I'm not going to turn down the checks. Amount will vary depending on market forces and how much energy your system produces, but as an example: Since installing my system in 2015, I've received $5700 from SREC sales. (That's after paying a commission to have someone else deal with the SREC auction process for me.) WARNING: There are periodic threats to not renew the SREC program, so don't count on this income being there forever... but it's a nice bonus while we've got it.

For what "non-refundable credit" means, see some of the past answers, such as [How do non-refundable tax credits combine with fully refundable tax credits](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/146133/how-do-non-refundable-tax-credits-combine-with-fully-refundable-tax-credits)

Comment: The idea of carbon credits is that it is supposed to give an incentive to reduce pollution instead of setting fixed numbers. How much is it worth to reduce pollution by X amount? It's unrealistic to say, "We must eliminate all pollution no matter what the cost." You might be willing to pay an extra $10 per month on your electric bill to pay for pollution control measures. Would you be willing to pay an extra $100 per month? $10,000 per month? There's a limit somewhere. Carbon credits put a dollar amount on each pound of pollutants. ...

Comment: ... If a utility can reduce pollution by X while spending less than the cost of the carbon credit, they'll spend the money and reduce the pollution. If it would cost more, then they'll buy the credit. This punishes the utility that pollutes and rewards the one that doesn't. One could certainly debate if it's a good idea in principle or if it is implemented well, and ultimately that's going to come down to a matter of opinion, but that's the reasoning behind it.

Comment: I understand the intent. Problem with it is that it dis-incentivizes making an up-front investment to achieve the greater improvement, and the additional incentive for those of us producing the "green" energy is less needed than it used to be. It exists, we're intended to take advantage of it and I certainly do so, but I'm not convinced it's achieving the goal it was designed for.

Comment: Put it this way - would you put up the solar on your roof without the carbon offset income? If the answer is yes - then the income you're getting is of course welcome for you, but is not actually paying for any carbon offsets since it doesn't actually incentivize you to reduce *more* carbon footprint than what you otherwise would.

Comment: I think I would. I'm pretty sure I'm atypical. I'm also pretty sure I'm nitpicking; anything that builds the idea that we can live without burning fossil fuels is a Good Thing even if only from an educational point of view.